# typescript currying call results and function definition

Tags: typescript

```
export const a= {
    b:
    (): c => (d, e) => {
         return d+e
       }
```

I am having trouble understanding what the code above does. I am confused by the usage of `():` what exactly is the b function if it is translated into plain javascript? If I call `a.b()`, what actually happens?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find solutions to stuff like this is using the typescript online compiler.
If you look here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAxlC8UCGA7EBuAUJiAPMA9gE7CwEoDOpSCUA3plFAEYBcjTUAFAJSuwIAfNwAmAGigQeQ+h05QiEYAFciKKCKgBqSXKgBfTPqA

You can see that the function b returns the function:

```
(d, e) => {
    return d+e
}
```

and this function is of type c.

Comment: does the return type of 'd+e' have to be same as defined in c?

Comment: c is going to be type `(d: any, e:any)=>any`

Comment: i guess i am still a bit confused, if c has 2 parameters d and e, and b is of type c, why b does not have any parameter while we still call it as a.b() rather than a.b(d,e)?

Answer (score 1):

> what exactly is the b function if it is translated into plain javascript?

```
export const aJS = {
  b: () => (d, e) => d + e
}

aJS.b()(3,4) // 7
```

So `aJS.b` is some kind of [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) or deferred function call.

---

In the TS version, `c` is a type. You can (1) leave out `c` and let the compiler infer the function type or (2) create a contextual function type and have the function arguments be inferred ([code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBjARgLhgCgEokA+AgEzzAFcBbLAUwCcAaGBquxp4xM8mAGp2aAL5oJUAJ4AHBjGBICYAIyd6zNmABM67rzI0NTCaEiw42peky4ChHIr4U2DAzAHCGYiXAB0WET4AMxsACzEAPSRMADsaJYBQaEwETDRcUA)):

(1)

```
const a = {
  b: () => (d: number, e: number) => d + e
}

a.b()(3, 4) // 7
```

(2)

```
type c = (n1: number, n2: number) => number

const a2 = {
  b: (): c => (d, e) => d + e
}

a2.b()(3, 4) // 7
```